# Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405aeb60 that was originally added here

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I know there are plenty of answer about this topic... but I am not able to find a solution to my problem. Its simple, an Activity:

```
public class DialogsActivity extends Activity {

Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
String token;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    mostrarDialogo();
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialogsactivitylayout);
    bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    token=bundle.getString("token");
    token=token.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    Log.i("Parse", "Token: "+token);


}

private void mostrarDialogo() {
    if(token.equals("nologin")){
        AlertDialog.Builder nologin = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogsActivity.this);
        nologin.setTitle(R.string.loginstring);
        nologin.setMessage(R.string.nologin);
        nologin.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }

                });


        nologin.show(); 
    }else if(token.equals("nocon")){
        AlertDialog.Builder nocon = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogsActivity.this);
        nocon.setTitle(R.string.loginstring);
        nocon.setMessage(R.string.timeout);
        nocon.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                });
        nocon.show();

    }else if(token.equals("oklogin")){

        AlertDialog.Builder start=new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogsActivity.this);
        start.setTitle(R.string.warn);
        start.setMessage(R.string.service);
        start.setNegativeButton(R.string.accept,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                });
        //finish();
        start.show();
    }else if(token!="nocon" && token!="nologin" && token!="oklogin"){
        AlertDialog.Builder error=new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogsActivity.this);
        error.setTitle(R.string.unknownerror);
        error.setMessage(R.string.unkerrortext);
        error.setPositiveButton(R.string.accept,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                        return;

                    }
                });
        error.show();
    }



}



}
```

And when the Activity is run, a stacktrace:

```
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737): Activity com.publidirecta.vinceriazafata.DialogsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405aeb60 that was originally added here
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.publidirecta.vinceriazafata.DialogsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405aeb60 that was originally added here
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:263)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:171)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:114)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:809)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at com.publidirecta.vinceriazafata.DialogsActivity.mostrarDialogo(DialogsActivity.java:88)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at com.publidirecta.vinceriazafata.DialogsActivity.onResume(DialogsActivity.java:20)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-21 11:46:25.140: E/WindowManager(15737):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error jumps always on the .show() method, depending of the value of token variable it enters in one if or in another.
And, as you can see, the dialogs are always dismissed. Any help? Thank you!

Comment: what value you get in Log.i() and also use equalsIgnoreCase() instead of equals() and try it.

Comment: The value I receive in the bundle is ok. That is not the problem. But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Fustigador: is this the complete stacktrace ?

Comment: Yes, it is complete stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your dialog before showing it.

For example:

```
nocon.create().show();
```

instead

```
nocon.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use

```
dialog.create().show();
```

I have modified you code to make it simple

```
private void mostrarDialogo() {
    if(token.equals("nologin")){
    showDialog(R.string.loginstring,R.string.nologin,R.string.cancel)

    }else if(token.equals("nocon")){
    showDialog(R.string.loginstring,R.string.timeout,R.string.cancel);       


    }else if(token.equals("oklogin")){
    showDialog(R.string.warn,R.string.service,R.string.accept);

    }else if(token!="nocon" && token!="nologin" && token!="oklogin"){
    showDialog(R.string.unknownerror,R.string.unkerrortext,R.string.accept);
   }

}

void showDialog(String title,String msg,String buttonText)
{
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogsActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle(title);
        dialog.setMessage(msg);
        dialog.setPositiveButton(buttonText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                    return;

                }
            });
    dialog.create().show();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem seems to be with the `Context` object with which you are creating `AlertDialog` in `onResume()`.
Whenever you need to pass/use `Context` it is always advisable to use `getApplicationContext()` object wherever possible instead of `ActivityContext`.

Replacing `DialogsActivity.this` with `getApplicationContext()` should work properly.
Hope this helps.

Comment: getApplicationContext() is required when you want the scope throughout the application here the dialog is called in the same activity so DialogsActivity.this is fine.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you on that. However I was talking about general scenario :)